# Indeterminate state for toggle buttons?

Tags: touch-screen, toggle

I'm working on a tablet based application where an agent would be going through and answering a series of yes/no questions.  This is running on Windows 7 and naturally the standard windows controls aren't as touch friendly as they could be.

Currently the Yes/No questions are presented as a pair of radio buttons, but we're considering making these more modern / touch friendly, and we're looking at replacing them with a windows phone style toggle button.

The gotcha is that our design requirement does not permit us to have any of these yes/no answers defaulted to either option, that is the control must be in an indeterminate state on initial display (the user can't put the control in an indeterminate state themselves).

So the only design I can think of would be a toggle switch where the thumb of the switch sits right in the middle, then the user goes down the form either touching the left or right side of the control, or alternatively, flicking the thumb left or right to answer the questions.  Does this seem like an intuitive way to present the control?

Comment: What exactly isn't touch friendly about a radio button? And what does "modern" mean? How are radio buttons not "modern"?

Comment: The radio buttons, as presented are easy to miss, to the point where most of the agents resort to using a stylus.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Radio buttons are actually the most accurate (requirements match standard behavior) control for this. Just make larger, custom radio buttons that are easier touch targets. Remember to allow the label to also act as a touch target for the radio button.

Toggle buttons are **not** the right control, because the user does not have the power to use them as intended... you cannot 'toggle' back to no answer. Do not use controls, even fashionable ones, if you must alter their normal behavior to have them perform as desired. The alterations will confuse the user.

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about it, this seems to be the best approach.

Comment: I'd agree radio buttons are probably the best match for this. I would like to point out though that I've never personally seen a _standard_ way to toggle radio buttons back to "no answer" either. Also, a good read on the indeterminate radio button state and its difference in the HTML 4/5 specs: http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-radio-buttons/

Comment: Wait... Brandorf specifically stated that toggling back to 'No Answer' is **disallowed**: *(the user can't put the control in an indeterminate state themselves)*

Comment: ...so toggles would be fine except that they don't have a neutral _initial_ state.

Comment: Exactly.  It was awkwardly worded, but my question really centered on _what would the indeterminate state of a toggle look like?_ We've opened a dialog with legal to see if we can remove the indeterminate initial state requirement.

Comment: To be fair, the requirement is important. You **must** be able to tell if someone skipped answering something. I still think that the most usable answer is the one I gave, but I can see the reasoning behind wanting a rocker control.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want a rocker switch, then you can clarify any ambiguity of the image by using a little text flair.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flwJLX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Regardless of the graphic you use in the middle, the text labels will reinforce your physical metaphor with a direct 'lit text' metaphor indicating which option is enabled. I chose red and green, but red/green colorblindness is not really an issue since the intent is more that the text is 'on' than which color it is.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something with two controls would work?

[image]

Comment: Well, this is pretty much exactly as it currently behaves, but with the stock radio buttons.

Comment: Does "(No is back in initial state)" mean "The No button is back in its initial state because the user has clicked Yes" *or* "Click No to go back to the initial state"? If it's the latter, it's non-standard because clicking No should select No. Re-clicking Yes might unselect Yes without selecting No, though.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use a rocker switch. To much room for ambiguity. What is the middle state? I'd use an on off button and a toggle. Radio buttons for your example are the best way to go.

[image]